# Prove that the Frobenius map is a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

I want to prove that the Frobenius map $\phi$ is a homomorphism from the group of points on an elliptic curve $E(F_{2^k})$ to itself (endomorphism). It is trivial to check that if a point $P \in E$ then so is $\phi(P)$. However, i cannot find a simple way to show that $\phi$ respects the group structure i.e. $\phi(P+Q)=\phi(P)+\phi(Q)$.

Comment: What is $E(F_{2^k})$?

Comment: Sorry. It is the group of points over the field $F_{2^k}$ over an elliptic curve $E$.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the group operation in terms of chords and tangents. So if the chord $L$
connecting $P$ and $Q$ has equation $ax+by+c=0$, then the chord $\phi(L)$ connecting $\phi(P)$ and $\phi(Q)$ has equation $\phi(a)x+\phi(b)y+\phi(c)=0$. If $L$ intersects $E$ at a third point $R$, then $\phi(L)$ intersects $E$ at the point $\phi(R)$ (here it is essential that the defining equation of $E$ has coefficients invariant under $\phi$.

Do the same with tangents.

Comment: IIRC there is a slicker way in Silverman's book. Something along the lines of every automorphism of the function field automatically respecting the group operation.

Comment: I understand your method. However, i don't see how it implies that $\phi(P+Q) = \phi(P)+\phi(Q)$. Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: You get the point $P+Q$ by drawing that chord $L_1$ via $P$ and $Q$, letting $R$ be the third point of intersection, and then drawing a vertical line $L_2$ through $R$ (or a line via $R$ and the point at infinity), and $P+Q$ is then the third point $S$ of intersection between $E$ and $L_2$. Now to compute $\phi(P)+\phi(Q)$ you first draw the line connecting them. This is $\phi(L_1)$. It intersects $E$ at the point $\phi(R)$, so we get $\phi(P)+\phi(Q)$ as the point of intersection of $E$ and the vertical line through $\phi(R)$. But that vertical line is $\phi(L_2)$, so...

Comment: (cont'd) the point of intersection is $\phi(S)$. In other words, because $\phi$ is a bijection and $\phi(E)=E$, we get for all lines $L$ that $$\phi(E\cap L)=\phi(E)\cap\phi(L)=E\cap\phi(L).$$